# Метод toUpperCase() что он делает?

Tags: java

Вот кусочек кода

```
String Str = new String("Добро пожаловать на somesite.su");

System.out.print("Возвращаемое значение: ");
System.out.println(Str.toUpperCase());
```

в конце метод `.toUpperCase()` я посмотрел лог не могу понять на что он вияет какого его роль?зачем он нужен ?

Comment: Его роль проста - намекнуть, что пора уже [разобраться с базовым английским](https://translate.google.com/?source=gtx_m#ht/ru/to%20Upper%20Case).

Comment: @KoVadim а почему язык оригинала стоит "Креольский"? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Преобразует символы строки в верхний регистр